# Uploaded File Size in LoadRunner

Tags: loadrunner, vugen, microfocus

We are creating a LoadRunner script which will upload the files for multiple users through Web/HTTP protocol. However we need to check the uploaded file size during runtime through LoadRunner script only and accordingly do exception handling while test is running.

Does anyone know on how to check **file upload size** with LoadRunner function itself?

Please note downloading the uploaded file to check the download file size is not possible - to avoid any network congestion or extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help me to understand your question better.  Are you suggesting that the file upload process for your site is in question, that it is not yet functionally vetted as working for one?

Or, are you trying to generate some sort of normalized datapoint because you are uploading files of various sizes, which then result in response times of various times, where then you want to generate a normalized rate, such as bytes/time?

You can check the file size with core language functions.

Suggested by a colleague, Uttiyan Nandy, on Facebook as I was investigating some attributes for web_get_int_property() and noting that HTTP_INFO_UPLOAD_SIZE does not exist as an object.   Consider pairing web_get_int_property() with HTTP_INFO_TOTAL_REQUEST_STAT for the full size of the request, which may include your file attachment as well as headers, ....

Comment: Thanks James for the inputs. I am trying to validate the different file sizes vs the response times of the requests and do some file writing for size vs response time. One of the methods could be , as you mentioned to calculate the file size using C language core function and then get the respective response time however I was checking if we have some internal function/property available in Loadrunner itself like we check for download size. I will try to calculate the request size without attachment and then use the property you mentioned to start with.

Comment: To make your life easier, turn on time-taken and C-S bytes (Client to server bytes) in your HTTP request log for test and prod.   Then you can use a simple log processing tool during your test or at the end of the test to display throughput numbers, or a scatter graph of time vs size,perhaps even deriving a function in R from the dataset.   You can also import the data into LR analysis at the end of the test - consult your manual on importing data into Analysis.